# How can I change the Ctrl+Shift+U shortcut (and others) to work as expected in Texmaker instead of being caught by Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.04, latex

I recently installed 18.04 on my laptop, and when I write LaTex documents, I use Texmaker. One of the default configurations of Texmaker is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> allows me to quickly raise exponents. However, that is also a default keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu 18.04, and that command somehow has precedence now when I am in the Texmaker window.

I did not have this problem in 16.04. I have tried finding the command in the keyboard settings to disable it, but it is not in the GUI. I am still unsure of where the actual keyboard shortcut commands are stored in Ubuntu or how I would manually change them.

This could easily be solved by changing the command in Texmaker, but I want to be able to modify other commands in the Ubuntu system.

Also, why is the Ubuntu command now taking precedence over the command in Texmaker?

I am using the default desktop environment, GNOME 3. When I run the following command `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i Ctrl | grep -i Shift` I get:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot-clip '<Ctrl><Shift>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast '<Ctrl><Shift><Alt>R'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings move-tab-left '<Ctrl><Shift>Page_Up'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings move-tab-right '<Ctrl><Shift>Page_Down'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings close-tab '<Ctrl><Shift>w'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings paste '<Ctrl><Shift>v'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings new-tab '<Ctrl><Shift>t'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings copy '<Ctrl><Shift>c'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings close-window '<Ctrl><Shift>q'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings new-window '<Ctrl><Shift>n'
```

But running `dconf dump / | grep -i Ctrl | grep -i Shift` doesn't output anything to the screen.

Comment: How many keyboard layouts do you have? How do you switch them (with which shortcut)? Add output of the command `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i Ctrl | grep -i Shift` and `dconf dump / | grep -i Ctrl | grep -i Shift` to the question. Which desktop environment do you use?

Comment: @N0rbert I only see 4 and none of it includes Ctrl + Shift + u. This is the actual output:
`org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot-clip '<Ctrl><Shift>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast '<Ctrl><Shift><Alt>R'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings move-tab-left '<Ctrl><Shift>Page_Up'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings move-tab-right '<Ctrl><Shift>Page_Down'`. The second command prints nothing for me.

Comment: Here is the perfect solution for me https://superuser.com/a/1392682/579771 via `ibus-setup`.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [Stack Exchange Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/358749/how-to-disable-ctrlshiftu-in-ubuntu-linux?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) You need to run:

```
im-config -n none
```

The screen with the Unity interface looks like this afterwards:

[image: settings language.png]

Notice the last field has changed from `iBus` to `none`. Unfortunately I don't have a Gnome Desktop screenshot for you.

A [newer method](https://wiki.gnome.org/ThreePointFive/Features/IBus#How_to_use_other_IM_frameworks) (if `im-config` is not installed on your system) is with `gsettings`:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
```

Comment: The Gnome interface is very similar. I do have `im-config` installed so I ran the first command and the **Keyboard input method system** displayed "none". I am still having the same issue. I also tried to run the second command, but still the same issue.  I rebooted the system after each command.